# UWP compiles but there is an error DEP3321

Tags: winapi, mobile, xamarin.forms, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am running a few experiments on mobile app development using Xamarin Forms (using a .Net Standard library) in VS 2017. Android runs fine (Android SDK is installed), but I am running into a problem with my UWP project.

The UWP project compiles ok, but when debugging I get the error code DEP3321 which says something about my deployment target using Windows Runtime Version 10.0.16299.0 but that I have version 10.0.14393 installed. I have tried manually installing Windows 10 SDK (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) but i get a message that i am actually up to date to the version 10.0.16299

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYJru.jpg]

I have tried changing the minimum version in the properties of the VS project as I have read in other similar posts reporting this particular error and have played around it in all combinations too only to get a lot more errors  stating that for my project, the target version for netstandard 2 is fixed and that a reference through a project with version 10.0.14393 is not possible

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOIwt.jpg]

First time I ran into this error I thought it might had to do with my VS 2017 being opened at the time I ran the Windows SDK 10 install. I read that it might not work very well. So I closed it and ran the installer again. I do see what looks like the corresponding folders on my drive:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGl4e.jpg]

Anyone had this problem? Any suggestions?

NOTE: I do have 2 instances of VS installed on my machine: VS 2010 and VS 2017

Comment: If you want to use .NET Standard 2.0 library, you have to set the min version to 16299 at least. Anniverary update does not support .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: @Martin Thanks, it makes sense, but my problem remains, I want tthe deployment target to be 16299 but I get the error that its not installed. When I run the Windows 10 SDK says it is installed....I do seem to find it in the Program files folders, but not on the Registry though

Comment: I would suggest doing repair of VS2017 via the visual studio installer if that does not help

Comment: When you receive an error message, please provide the **exact** error message in the question. Also, screenshots are tempting, but textual information is what counts. Always assume that someone who knows the answer to your question cannot see images. Besides, it's unclear what the Windows API has anything to do with this.

Comment: @IInspectable, I would provide the original error message, problem is that its not in english and german is not understood by all, that is why I attempted to translate it best I could.

Comment: You can change Visual Studio's UI language easily. And that is really what you want to do.

Comment: to deploy the app you need Fall Creators update 1709/Build 16299 installed not 14393

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes, thats it, looks like i need to upgrade my Enterprise Windows 10 edition. I guess that is why the SDK alone was not working. thanks all for your comments